# Why does sqlite stop at any row with a NULL when using create table (won't accept any more insert statements after that)?

Tags: sqlite

I was trying to create this table using SQLite but it only creates the first 6 rows after which it stops because of NULL

```
create table manufacturing_facilities ( 
    company nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    countryID nvarchar(3) NOT NULL,
    number_of_locations integer NULL,
    Primary Key(company, countryID));

insert into manufacturing_facilities values('Intel','USA',8);   
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('Intel','ISR',1);   
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('Intel','CHN',3);   
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('Intel','VT',1);    
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('TEVA','ISR',60);   
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('TEVA','USA',20);   
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('TEVA','RUS',NULL); 
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('TEVA','IND',1);    
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('TEVA','DE',NULL);  
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('TEVA','JPN',1);    
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('TEVA','UK',2); 
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('Tesla','USA',1);   
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('Tesla','CHN',1);   
insert into manufacturing_facilities values('Toyota','JPN',16);
```

I am not sure what to do in this case?

Comment: [Works for me.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=26195317275884943d1d8bfd6b72ee55)

Comment: really? did you check the data view and actually see that the table had more than 6 rows?

Comment: Well, the `SELECT` lists 14 rows, exactly the number of `INSERT` statements...

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7rffFXi1StLDGqsXpvB61S/0

Comment: yeah it works on this site. these types of issues are the worst. makes no sense

Comment: Why do you say *it stops*? Do you get any error? How do you execute these statements?

Comment: No it just creates a table with only the first 6 rows. Anyway I restarted my pc and it works now. clearly i need a new pc.